# Wrapping sets of enums

Tags: c++, enums

I've been trying to create a master enum type with children enums, to improve readability and usage. Here is an example of what I mean :

```
enum TileType {
   enum Ground {
      FLAT,
      SLOPE // ...
   },
   enum Props {
      SIGN // ...
   }
   // ...
};
```

which could be referenced as `TileType type = TileType::Ground::FLAT` for a better hierarchy.

I thought of wrapping enums in a namespace :

```
namespace TileType {
   enum Ground {
      FLAT,
      SLOPE // ...
   };
   enum Props {
      SIGN // ...
   };
   // ...
};
```

I can use it as `int TileType::Ground::FLAT`, but I won't be able to distinguish `Ground` of `Props` since `Ground::FLAT` and `Props::SIGN` will both be 0.

Using `enum class` might be what I'm looking for, but I won't be able to have `TileType type = TileType::Ground::Flat` since each enum will be a different class.

Comment: In your namespace version, what about `SIGN=SLOPE+1`?

Comment: That could do it, but as the ... suggests, this list will grow as I add features and it will quickly become impossible to maintain.

Comment: If you keep the last enum in each set with a constant (unused) name (`GROUND_LAST`), then `SIGN=GROUND_LAST` you wouldn't need to do more than to add the new enums before the `_LAST` enum in the sets.

Comment: Indeed, it is working as planned! Thank you

Comment: Good to hear! Cheers

Comment: Remember that if you use these enums for any persistant file structures, adding intermediate values in the middle will shift around the values of following constants, which can possibly make backwards compatibility a huge hassle. Having gaps between the values of child enums might be a good idea, because when time comes to insert Ground::WATERY, it allows Props::SIGN to retain its previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum TileTypes
{
    GroundTypes = 1000
    PropTypes = 2000
}

enum Ground
{
    FIRST_GROUND = GroundTypes,
    FLAT = FIRST_GROUND,
    SLOPE,
    ...,
    INVALID_GROUND
}

enum Props
{
    FIRST_PROP = PropTypes,
    SIGN = FIRST_PROP,
    ...,
    INVALID_PROP
}
```

This is the way I usually handle groupable type definitions for persistent structures. The advantages here are:

- Subtypes can be nested as desired
- There exist gaps between values of different subtypes, so that the values of Props are not dependant of the number of Ground types
- It is easy to check if a value is of type

  `bool isGround(int value) { return FIRST_GROUND <= value && INVALID_GROUND > value; }`
- Easy-to-read and not highly sophisticated syntax

Answer (score 0):

An enum of enum's is generally not good practice.

Consider wrapping the enum's in a struct (or separate structs), or better, a class.

As for the both enum's starting at 0, you can do what some of the comments have suggested, or pick starting ranges wildly different from each other.

But this is a context thing you the programmer need to resolve (I don't see an issue with both starting at 0 as long as the variables distinguish the types).

Example

```
struct TileType 
{
   enum Ground {
      FLAT = 0,
      SLOPE = 1, // ...
   };
   enum Props {
      SIGN = 9999 // ...
   };
};
```